# Unable to open CKFinder - Invalid resource type

Tags: ckfinder

I'm trying to set up a new instance of CKFinder 3 (integrated with CKEditor) and am racking my brain trying to track down and resolve this problem. Sorry for the wall of text.

When I try to open the Browse window (as soon as the window is opened), I just get the loading throbber and the following log generated in the upload folder (I have debug logging turned on).

```
[2015-10-19 23:05:41] CKFinder.ERROR: exception 'CKSource\CKFinder\Exception\InvalidResourceTypeException' with message 'Invalid resource type: ' in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\*snip*\resources\other\ckfinder\core\connector\php\vendor\cksource\ckfinder\src\CKSource\CKFinder\Config.php:376

Stack trace:
#0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\*SNIP*\resources\other\ckfinder\core\connector\php\vendor\cksource\ckfinder\src\CKSource\CKFinder\ResourceType\ResourceTypeFactory.php(34): CKSource\CKFinder\Config->getResourceTypeNode('') 
#1 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\*SNIP*\resources\other\ckfinder\core\connector\php\vendor\cksource\ckfinder\src\CKSource\CKFinder\Filesystem\Folder\WorkingFolder.php(96): CKSource\CKFinder\ResourceType\ResourceTypeFactory->getResourceType('') 
#2 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\*SNIP*\resources\other\ckfinder\core\connector\php\vendor\cksource\ckfinder\src\CKSource\CKFinder\CKFinder.php(117): CKSource\CKFinder\Filesystem\Folder\WorkingFolder->__construct(Object(CKSource\CKFinder\CKFinder)) 
#3 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\*SNIP*\resources\other\ckfinder\core\connector\php\vendor\pimple\pimple\src\Pimple\Container.php(112): CKSource\CKFinder\CKFinder->CKSource\CKFinder\{closure}(Object(CKSource\CKFinder\CKFinder)) 
#4 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\*SNIP*\resources\other\ckfinder\core\connector\php\vendor\cksource\ckfinder\src\CKSource\CKFinder\CKFinder.php(288): Pimple\Container->offsetGet('working_folder') 
#5 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\*SNIP*\resources\other\ckfinder\core\connector\php\vendor\cksource\ckfinder\src\CKSource\CKFinder\Command\CommandAbstract.php(68): CKSource\CKFinder\CKFinder->getWorkingFolder() 
#6 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\*SNIP*\resources\other\ckfinder\core\connector\php\vendor\cksource\ckfinder\src\CKSource\CKFinder\CommandResolver.php(150): CKSource\CKFinder\Command\CommandAbstract->checkPermissions() 
#7 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\*SNIP*\resources\other\ckfinder\core\connector\php\vendor\symfony\http-kernel\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel.php(133): CKSource\CKFinder\CommandResolver->getController(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request)) 
#8 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\*SNIP*\resources\other\ckfinder\core\connector\php\vendor\symfony\http-kernel\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel.php(66): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1) 
#9 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\*SNIP*\resources\other\ckfinder\core\connector\php\vendor\cksource\ckfinder\src\CKSource\CKFinder\CKFinder.php(491): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true) 
#10 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\*SNIP*\resources\other\ckfinder\core\connector\php\vendor\cksource\ckfinder\src\CKSource\CKFinder\CKFinder.php(261): CKSource\CKFinder\CKFinder->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request)) 
#11 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\*SNIP*\resources\other\ckfinder\core\connector\php\connector.php(20): CKSource\CKFinder\CKFinder->run() 
#12 {main} [] []
```

The URL I'm using to access CKFinder is `http://*SNIP*/resources/other/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Images`, so the resource type is definitely set as required. It also definitely exists in the configuration as shown below.

This is the exception logged when trying to use the Quick Upload facilities:

```
[2015-10-19 23:06:19] CKFinder.ERROR: exception 'CKSource\CKFinder\Exception\UnauthorizedException' with message 'Unauthorized' in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\*SNIP*\resources\other\ckfinder\core\connector\php\vendor\cksource\ckfinder\src\CKSource\CKFinder\Command\CommandAbstract.php:75
Stack trace: 
#0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\*SNIP*\resources\other\ckfinder\core\connector\php\vendor\cksource\ckfinder\src\CKSource\CKFinder\CommandResolver.php(150): CKSource\CKFinder\Command\CommandAbstract->checkPermissions() 
#1 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\*SNIP*\resources\other\ckfinder\core\connector\php\vendor\symfony\http-kernel\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel.php(133): CKSource\CKFinder\CommandResolver->getController(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request)) 
#2 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\*SNIP*\resources\other\ckfinder\core\connector\php\vendor\symfony\http-kernel\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel.php(66): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1) 
#3 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\*SNIP*\resources\other\ckfinder\core\connector\php\vendor\cksource\ckfinder\src\CKSource\CKFinder\CKFinder.php(491): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true) 
#4 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\*SNIP*\resources\other\ckfinder\core\connector\php\vendor\cksource\ckfinder\src\CKSource\CKFinder\CKFinder.php(261): CKSource\CKFinder\CKFinder->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request)) 
#5 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\*SNIP*\resources\other\ckfinder\core\connector\php\connector.php(20): CKSource\CKFinder\CKFinder->run() 
#6 {main} [] []
```

And some selected relevant portions of config.php (NB. `$_SESSION['guid']` is set earlier and is not the cause of the problem):

```
...

$config['authentication'] = function() {
    if (isset($_SESSION['guid'])) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};

...

$config['backends'][] = array(
    'name'         => 'default',
    'adapter'      => 'local',
    'baseUrl'      => '/resources/uploads/'.$_SESSION['guid'].'/',
    //  'root'         => '', // Can be used to explicitly set the CKFinder user files directory.
    'chmodFiles'   => 0777,
    'chmodFolders' => 0755,
    'filesystemEncoding' => 'UTF-8',
);

...

$config['defaultResourceTypes'] = '';

$config['resourceTypes'][] = array(
    'name'              => 'Files', // Single quotes not allowed.
    'directory'         => 'files',
    'maxSize'           => 0,
    'allowedExtensions' => 'doc,docx,gif,jpeg,jpg,pdf,png,ppt,pptx,xls,xlsx',
    'deniedExtensions'  => '',
    'backend'           => 'default'
);

$config['resourceTypes'][] = array(
    'name'              => 'Images',
    'directory'         => 'images',
    'maxSize'           => 0,
    'allowedExtensions' => 'gif,jpeg,jpg,png',
    'deniedExtensions'  => '',
    'backend'           => 'default'
);

...

$config['accessControl'][] = array(
    'role'                => '*',
    'resourceType'        => '*',
    'folder'              => '/',

    'FOLDER_VIEW'         => true,
    'FOLDER_CREATE'       => true,
    'FOLDER_RENAME'       => true,
    'FOLDER_DELETE'       => true,

    'FILE_VIEW'           => true,
    'FILE_UPLOAD'         => true,
    'FILE_RENAME'         => true,
    'FILE_DELETE'         => true,

    'IMAGE_RESIZE'        => true,
    'IMAGE_RESIZE_CUSTOM' => true
);
...
```

Paths are set correctly and have the correct permissions. CKFinder successfully creates the '' folder as well as the .ckfinder subfolder. If using the quick upload facility, it also creates the 'image' or 'files' subfolder but doesn't upload anything.

The quick upload facilities show the 'unauthorized' exception even when I explicitly set `$config['authentication'] = true;`.

Other relevant information:

- PHP 5.6.7
- Windows Server 2012 R2 / IIS 8.5
- CKEditor 4.5.3

I've been racking my brain on this and trying to trace it for the last couple of weeks, so any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please add a JavaScript code that starts CKEditor and CKFinder?

Comment: At the moment I'm not using Javascript (though I've tried it too with the same result). I've set the following options when initialising CKEditor: `filebrowserBrowseUrl`, `filebrowserUploadUrl`, `filebrowserImageBrowseUrl` and `filebrowserImageUploadUrl`

They're set to the relevant URLs, with the `type` option given as a parameter ("Files" or "Images" respectively)

Answer (score 3):

I found that explicitly listing the default resource types in config.php fixed this issue. I think it's a bug because the [documentation](http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder3-php/configuration.html#configuration_options_defaultResourceTypes) says that all resource types are loaded if this field is left as an empty string, but leaving it as an empty string seems to break the initialisation process.

For example, in config.php, replace:

```
$config['defaultResourceTypes'] = '';
```

with:

```
$config['defaultResourceTypes'] = 'Files,Images';
```